# 'psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "table" does not exist' when makemigrations

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlite, django-migrations

I have a django app (Django==4.1.2) and I am trying to migrate from sqlite3 to postgres.

I have been following multiples guides on how to do this, and they all do more or less the same and those are the steps I followed:

1. Get a dumpdata with `python manage.py dumpdata > whole.json`
2. Create db and user and connect to it
3. Config settings.py to set everything to the new database
4. Delete old migrations
5. run `python manage.py makemigrations` or `python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb`

---

There are more steps, but I am stuck in this 5th one getting 'psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "table" does not exist'

Looking for solutions I've come to [this](https://gist.github.com/sirodoht/f598d14e9644e2d3909629a41e3522ad?permalink_comment_id=2580695#gistcomment-2580695) post which may help someone, though I might not doing it right or something but commenting models have done nothing for me.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you remove all files from the migrations folder?

Comment: Yes I tried removing everything and also removing all py and pyc files but "\_\_init\_\_.py". Neither of those worked